# How to pass a comma separated list (from an option page) as an array in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a custom option menu in the Admin (Dashboard) page in WordPress.

The idea is to allow administrators to enter Post IDs to restrict as a comma separated value (e.g. "100, 102, 104") in Dashboard. I'd like to pass the comma separated value as an array to restrict access to the posts with the Post IDs.

To restrict the access, I tried to get the value in a theme file:

```
$restricted_ids = array();
$restricted_ids = get_option('_s_theme_options')['restricted_post_ids'];
if(is_single ($restricted_ids)) && !is_user_logged_in()) {
// My code here
}
```

I tested it and found that the variable "$restricted_ids" does not get the Post Ids as expected. For example, if I enter '123, 456', $restricted_ids receives it as an array with the values '1, 2, 3...' not '123, 456'.
How can I correct the code for "$restricted_ids" to receive the entered Post Ids as an array correctly?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: mybe base64 encode the entry?

Comment: @Jester. Thanks for your comment. However, I am not so technical... Further clue to resolve this issue?

Comment: Will PHP `implode()` work for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing spaces from your string, and then splitting it into an array with `explode()`:

```
$restricted_ids = array();

$post_ids = str_replace(' ', '', get_option('_s_theme_options')['restricted_post_ids']);
$restricted_ids = explode(',', $post_ids);

if(is_single ($restricted_ids) && !is_user_logged_in()) {
  // Do the things
}
```